# Sylow Subgroup is

Tags: sylow-theory

G be a finite group.P is a Sylow p-subgroup which is contained in the center of G.Show that there is a normal subgroup N of G such that G=PN.(Herstein problem,page 103 prob 16)
Give some idea.P is normal in G,but can't proceed further. Sorry I missed out N intersection P={1}

Answer (score 0):

Check [Frattini's Argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini's_argument), and take into account that

$$Z(G)\lhd G\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;N_G(P)=G$$

Comment: since Z(G) and P both are normal in G we will always get G=G by Frattini argument.It is not clear.

Comment: Frattini's argument says that $\;G=N_G(P)\,Z(G)\;$ , so...

Comment: But then what is the required N?

Comment: N should be proper normal subgroup of G

Comment: It is written clearly in the link I wrote you, @Via: a normal subgroup $\;H\;$,  which in our case is $\;Z(G)\;$ and a Sylow $\;p$-subgroup of $\;G\;$ contained in $\;H\;$, which is our $\;P\;$, then we get $$G=N_G(P)H\stackrel{\text{our case}}=G Z(G)=G$$ since $\;P\lhd G\iff H_G(P)=G\;$ ...!

Comment: Sorry @ Timbuc I missed it out,I added to the question that P meets N trivially.